# Runnig commands on remote unix server

Tags: shell, unix

I am working on a shell script. It is used to login to another remote server check for the existance of a file and it it doesnt it creates and if it does nothing happens.

I am trying to do this by,
ssh -i private_key server_name 'script to create new file'

After spending a long time thinking why it is not happening, it stuck to mind that the variable from where i am doing ssh will not be available in the server to which it goes. So I have to pass a variable. But I couldnt do so. But the logon part is smooth.

Please help.

Comment: Post what have you tried so far...

Answer (score 1):

If it's OK to update modification time of the file:

```
ssh -i keyfile server "touch '$newfile'"
```

otherwise

```
ssh -i keyfile server "[ -f '$newfile' ] && touch '$newfile'"
```

Those should work assuming your login shell is a Bourne-type shell.

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes, or switch up the quotes if you need single quotes for some parts.

```
"foo $bar baz"
'foo '"$bar"' baz'
```